# Nutch In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nutch

While configuring nutch ,there's a step under section "Establish the Eclipse environment for Nutch" on http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse which i am unable to understand.

The step no. 3 says

"In additon, we must maunally add EVERY individual plugin src/java and src/test folder, although this takes some time it is absolutely essential that this is done."

Which plugins is it talking of and how to add these plugins???

Need help as i am trying to run nutch on eclipse from past 2 days and still not able to get hold of it..

Thanks,

Comment: when i ran it, it displays he following errors.


    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved  compilation problems: 
 String cannot be resolved to a type
 Exception cannot be resolved to a type
 System cannot be resolved

 at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are still working on it. This is a super annoying step which you have to add src/test and src/java folder of **each** individual plugin to your class path.

Comment: Now, I am working on Ajax-Solr . Any idea how to install it on my system. Tutorials on the web are god-dam confusing.<br> Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The updated steps are here: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse.
 Now, you wont have to manually add each src/test and src.java directory to classpath :)